# cannot display comment list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just want to display comment list in the following way but something is wrong with my code and I cannot get expected result. Could you please check it and help me to find the mistake.

[image]

I get following result:

[image]

```
var item = $('<div>');

$.each(data.results, function(i, res) {                    

  var photo = $('<div>'),
      block1 = $('<div style="float: left;">'),
      block2 = $('<div>'),
      title = $('<h4>'),
      info = $('<p>');

  photo.html('<img src="xyz">');
  title.html('<hr/>'+res.name+','+res.country);
  info.html(res.comment_text);
  block1.append(photo); 
  block2.append(title, info);                   
  item.append(block1, block2);

});

$("#comments").html(item);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a clearing issue. You need to clear the parent divs. You can easily do so by adding a `clear` class to those items and applying the following CSS:

```
.clear:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Here is a [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpo1orka/).

It would have been better if you supplied the output HTML and preferably a fiddle to play with. Now you forced us to figure it out all by ourselves. Make your questions as clear and to the point as possible, so people will answer to you more quickly and thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

First off your selectors are bad, you have 3 vars that are calling the same thing. Use this as a guideline for your selectors. **[jQuery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)** Also it will be helpful to know what is failing exactly, maybe paste some HTML so we can better help you.

**Edit:** Try removing the block1 and block2 vars and see how it looks. With those selectors they are appending the photo and title info to the very first div. Try using the selector $(this) instead of block1 and block2.

**Edit2:** Ok so what is going on is your  item.append(block1, block2); part is adding the blocks you create to the first div.

**EDIT3:** You need to create a new div and add the new blocks to create the new "item" Something along the lines of item.append("< /div>< div>"+ photo + title + info+'< /div>')

**Edit 4:** Without knowing your html I can't really write any code for your situation I can only assume and guess.

Comment: tried in the way you described but still did not get the expected result.

Comment: I tried in that way but no result. Maybe you can write the code so that I could understand what do you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You should use stylesheets over inline styles, but essentially you just need to clear the float you're creating.

Change:

```
var item = $('<div>');
```

to:

```
var item = $('<div style="clear:left">'),
```

Comment: I have already used **float:left** for **block1**. Photo is inside the div **block1**. I also edited my code in the way you described but nothing changed.

Comment: still did not get expected layout

Answer (score 0):

where are you closing your elements? try with this code:

```
var item = $('<div/>');

$.each(data.results, function(i, res) {                    

    var photo = $('<div/>'),
        block1 = $('<div style="float: left;"></div>'),
        block2 = $('<div/>'),
        title = $('<h4/>'),
        info = $('<p/>');

    photo.html('<img src="xyz"/>');
    title.html('<hr/>'+res.name+','+res.country);
    info.html(res.comment_text);
    block1.append(photo); 
    block2.append(title, info);                   
    item.append(block1, block2);

});

$("#comments").html(item);
```